# How to efficiently return a list of whether a time series will go up by X% before it goes down by X% for each element in the series

Tags: python, performance

The function returns a list, pipHL, which has a result for each element in the timeseries, df.iloc[:,col_no)
It's incredibly slow. Is there a good way to do it efficiently in numpy or otherwise?

```
def pipHL(df,col_no, scale_percent):
    pipHL=[]
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        start=df.iloc[i,col_no]
        hightarget=start+start*scale_percent
        lowtarget=start-start*scale_percent
        for j in range(i+1,len(df)):
            if df.iloc[j,col_no]>=hightarget:
                pipHL.append(1)
                break
            if df.iloc[j,col_no]<=lowtarget:
                pipHL.append(0)
                break
            pipHL.append(0.5)
    return pipHL
```

Comment: Exactly what it does - just faster. Imagine you are trading - you want to enter a long trade if the price in the future will reach current_value*(1+scale_percent) before it reaches current_value*(1-scale_percent).

Comment: I want to return 1 if that is true, 0 if the opposite is true, and 0.5 if it never reaches either. I want that value stored for every element in the time series.